# Behavior of ImportString in Mathematica

Tags: import, string-manipulation

I tried the following commands

```
ImportString[
  "129,160,16,4
  130,160,16,4", "Data"] // FullForm
(* Out= List[List["129,160,16,4"],List["130,160,16,4"]] *)

ImportString[
  "129,160,16,4
  130,160,16,4
  131,160,16,4
  132,160,16,4", "Data"] // FullForm

(* Out= List[List[129,160,16,4],List[130,160,16,4],List[131,160,16,4],List[132,160,16,4]] *)
```

Note that in the first case, the output is a list of strings, whereas in the second case the output is a list of list of numbers.

- Why is this so ?
- Can I force the first case to return integers as in the second case?

Answer (score 10):

I have no idea why the first `ImportString` brings things in as strings, but if you import as "CSV" instead, it works as you want.

```
In[22]:= ImportString[
  "129,160,16,4
  130,160,14,5", "CSV"] // InputForm
Out[22]= {{129, 160, 16, 4}, {130, 160, 14, 5}}
```

You can use `InputForm` to force the display of quote marks; you don't need the much more verbose `FullForm`.

Comment: The "CSV" option is an elegant solution! thanks ..( & thanks for the InputForm gyaan )

Answer (score 10):

I think the problem is that there is no input format called "Data":

```
In[253]:= MemberQ[$ImportFormats, "Data"]

Out[253]= False
```

If I use "Table":

```
In[248]:= ImportString["129,160,16,4
130,160,16,4
131,160,16,4
132,160,16,4","Table"]//FullForm

Out[248]//FullForm=List[List["129,160,16,4"],List["130,160,16,4"],List["131,160,16,4"],List["132,160,16,4"]]
```

Comment: I am sure you are right, but why does `ImportString["129,160,16,4
   130,160,16,4", "Elements"]` give me `{"Data", "Grid"}`? ("Grid" seems to work OK)

Comment: @TomD Well, `ImportString` is just a specific `Import` wrapper, so `Import` is being called to import the "Data" from text string in the "default data format" (whatever that may be in this particular case). My guess is that the "default data format" changes between the two strings due to some internal algorithm.

Comment: @ no input format called "Data": thanks! ( confused with **"Data" data in a generic Mathematica form (list, string, etc.)** in the documentation